# Mouse and keyboard "frozen" for a second when opening laptop

Tags: windows-vista, laptop, keyboard, mouse

When I open my Compaq laptop running Windows Vista, the mouse and keyboard are "frozen" for 5-7 seconds before they become active and I can enter my password to unlock the computer. This is very annoying - do you know of any fixes? It seems like it takes a second to initialize the mouse and keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might see a slight improvement with Windows 7, or Windows XP (they are faster than Vista).

That said, all computers need a little bit of time to wake up devices. With a well-optimized system, the time can be negligible, otherwise, it can stretch.

Personally, 1 second is still within reasonable expectations - I've seen computers that need more than a minute to wake up due to all the bloatware and crap the user have installed.

Comment: True. all computers need some time to wake devices. As I was typing this, my keyboard and mouse froze.

Comment: It is rather annoying though, it is not really one second, more like 5 or 7.

Comment: I suggest you look towards optimizing Vista first. Majority of the slowness I would attribute to your Vista installation being bogged.